# Mutex alternative for process synchronisation/signalling with async support?

Tags: c#, mutex

Is there anything except for `Mutex` to synchronise two processes in a fault-tolerant fashion? Please bear with me...

There is a process A, it's a bit flaky, it needs to start process B in the background and continue. If process A successfully does its thing, it needs to signal process B to dispose, and moves on (it doesn't terminate and thread is reused). If process A dies due to exception, termination, etc. process B needs to detect it quickly and dispose of itself on its own. Process A is not a "process" rather a library executed by various hosts hence process B can't just wait for process A's name to disappear.

Enter Mutex.

Here process A represented by a test fixture, if successful it'll call `TestFixtureTearDown` and move on, or test runner might be killed and `TestFixtureTearDown` is never executed. As with the actual process, `TestFixtureTearDown` might be called by a different thread to one that ran `TestFixtureSetUp` and created the mutex, hence `ReleaseMutex` sometimes throws `ApplicationException : Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.`

1. Can I force `ReleaseMutex` in `TestFixtureTearDown` if it's being executed by a different thread or abandon mutex some other way?
2. Is there an alternative to Mutex that I can use for such fault-tolerant "reverse" wait/monitor scenario? Preferably without implementing process A sending heartbeats to process B and process B tracking intervals and timing out? Mutex felt like such an elegant solution except for occasional `ApplicationException` on asyncs.

.

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private Mutex _mutex;
        private Process _process;

        [TestFixtureSetUp]
        public void TestFixtureSetUp()
        {
            _mutex = new Mutex(true, "foo");
            _process = Process.Start("ConsoleApplication1.exe");
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test1() { /* Do stuff */ }

        [Test]
        public void Test2() { /* Do async stuff */ }

        [TestFixtureTearDown]
        public void TestFixtureTearDown()
        {
            _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            _process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting("foo");

            // Start doing stuff

            try { mutex.WaitOne(); }
            catch (AbandonedMutexException) { }
            finally { mutex.ReleaseMutex(); }

            // Finish doing stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a mix of `Mutex`, `Thread` and `ManualResetEvent`. For the googling folk of the future here's a verbose test:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MutexResetEvent.Tests
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private Mutex _mutex;
        private Thread _thread;
        private Process _process;
        private ManualResetEvent _event;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SetUp: #{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            _event = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            _thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thread: #{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

                _mutex = new Mutex(true, "MutexResetEvent");

                _process = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo =
                    {
                        FileName = "MutexResetEvent.Worker.exe",
                        //UseShellExecute = false,
                        //RedirectStandardOutput = true
                    }
                };
                //_process.OutputDataReceived += (o, a) => Console.WriteLine(a.Data);
                _process.Start();
                //_process.BeginOutputReadLine();

                while (!_event.WaitOne(1000))
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread: ...");

                Console.WriteLine("Thread: #{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

                _mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                _process.WaitForExit();
            });
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test: #{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            _thread.Start();

            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Test: ...");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            /*
            if (Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode() % 3 == 0)
                Environment.Exit(1);
            //*/
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TearDown: #{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task: #{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                _event.Set();
                //_thread.Join();
            }).Wait();

            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TearDown: ...");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace MutexResetEvent.Worker
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker: #{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            var mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting("MutexResetEvent");

            try
            {
                while (!mutex.WaitOne(1000))
                    Console.WriteLine("Worker: ...");
            }
            catch (AbandonedMutexException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Worker: AbandonedMutexException");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Worker: #{0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            Console.WriteLine("Worker: WOO HOO");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Semaphores do not have thread affinity. You can release a semaphore on a different thread than it was acquired on. Use a semaphore with a count of 1.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about semaphores but couldn't find anything on how to replicate the `AbandonedMutexException` behaviour, i.e. when  the starting process is killed unexpectedly and does not signal completion. It all when back to heartbeats on one side and timeouts on the other. Does it have an *abandoned* state/event?

Comment: I didn't think of that. I don't think semaphores are the answer then. Next idea would be to make the library transmit the PID it runs under to the "watcher" process using any IPC mechanism of choice. You can then wait for process termination.